# Can I put a specific condition statement to the increment in a for loop?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++ && (a specific condition to the incremented variable))
```

This would be use to stall a loop in a fake infinity until the said condition would be reached.

This point of this would be to have the loop still continue to do it's operation while stopping the increment of the i variable until a condition is met. For example if('another varible' < 9) then i can have it's normal increment. In other case if the condition is not met the i would not increment but the loop would still proceed the instruction one by one.

Comment: What is the specific condition?

Comment: you can put it in the condition part. `i < 9 && somecondition`

Comment: what do you mean by stall the loop?

Comment: wouldn't putting it in the condition box stop the loop if it wasn't met?

Comment: like the loop would still go on but the increment of i would seize for a while

Comment: You should specify the condition, and also explain thoroughly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: just a condition sorry like i++ only if ('another variable' < 9)

Comment: you can also do other stuff, also in the incremental part `i = somecondition ? i + 1 : someintfunc`

Comment: Instead of Frankensteining a *for loop*, why not just use a *while loop* and implement your own increment logic

Comment: It's possible to make a condition that affects the value of `i`, but it's probably not the best idea. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: No, it would repeat the loop body without incrementing the loop variable. Just put an `if` inside, however it smells like bad design. On the other hand you can pause a loop by awaiting a `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: Your edited post doesn't make sense. The for loop continues by incrementing/decrementing the counter. I think what you're looking at is a while loop, but you'll need to be more specific about your requirementn.

Comment: so a while loop with an if statement for the increment would be my best bet?

Comment: @Minixav55 yes, this would be the most readable, and draw less ire from your code reviewers

Comment: @Herohtar true, I should have said it's not a good idea.

Comment: Alright well thanks, I've only recently started in school to see the loops but i wanted to know if it was possible and if so if there was better alternative.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do this, but it is a bad idea. "for" loops should be *extremely simple and understandable*. Remember that the entire purpose of a `for` loop is that the "initialize/test/increment" pattern is *so common* that it deserves to have its own very clear syntax. Don't abuse that syntax by taking a hammer to it and forcing it to do something else. If you have complex requirements for your loop iteration, make that explicit in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++ && (a specific condition to the incremented variable))
```

as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i = (a specific condition to the incremented variable) ? i + 1 : i)
```

but this goes against the general purpose and intention of a for loop. It would just confuse your testers, reviewers and fellow coders.

And, not unimprortant, it would make the CLR optimizer give up and slow down `myArray[i]` by adding a range check each time.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking at is something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var otherCondition = 15;

while (counter < 9)
{
    if (otherCondition < 9)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

You're starting the `counter` at `0` just like in the `for` loop, and terminates when it reaches `9`. But increments only when the other condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate flow of control structure is a nested loop, with the inner loop "stalling" to infinity.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{
    do
    {
        Foo();
    } while (!condition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `i += (true/false) ? 1 : 0`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += (a specific condition to the incremented variable) ? 1 : 0)
```

For example:

```
var n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += (n++%2==0) ? 1 : 0) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Having said that it makes the code unnecessarily harder to read and to understand your intention.

The following two examples are much clearer.

```
int met = 0;
while(true) 
{
  if(a specific condition to the incremented variable) met++;
  if(met >= 9) break;
}
```

or

```
var met = 0;
while( met < 9 ) 
{
  if(a specific condition to the incremented variable) met++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `while` will be more helpful in this case:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 9)
{
    if (condition)
        i++;
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman The previous answer was for the question before the edit.

Comment: That's not the point. I just want to clarify what I had written.